# JQuery Deferred & cascading select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

On page load I'm trying to populate select boxes.  The URL to hit for data for `#select2` depends on the value of `#select1`. As the first select box is also populated from data received from an Ajax call, I can't know in advance what the selected option will be on page load.  `initData()` is called on body load.

I've tried the following, but in `initData()` `selectOneValue` is `null` when `getSelectData('#select2', 'urlBase/' + selectOneValue + '/urlSuffix');` is called.

```
function initData() {
    initEnvs().then(function () {
        var selectOneValue= $('#select1').val();
        getSelectData('#select2', 'urlBase/' + selectOneValue + '/urlSuffix');
    });
}

function initEnvs() {
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        getSelectData('#select1', someUrl);
        def.resolve();
    }).promise();
}

function getSelectData(selectId, urlFragment) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/data/" + urlFragment,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            appendSelectOptions(selectId, data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //handle error
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but this should work. Let me know if not.

```
function initData() {
    initEnvs().then(function () {
        var selectOneValue= $('#select1').val();
        console.log("============ 2");
        getSelectData('#select2', 'urlBase/' + selectOneValue + '/urlSuffix').then(function(data){
          console.log("Are we here?");
          appendSelectOptions('#select2', data);
        });
    });
}

function initEnvs() {
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        getSelectData('#select1', someUrl).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log("============");
            appendSelectOptions('#select1', data);
        });
        def.resolve();
    }).promise();
}

function getSelectData(selectId, urlFragment) {
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {      
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/data/" + urlFragment,
        dataType: "json"
    });
     def.resolve();
   }).promise();   
}

initData();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `selectOneValue` is still null with these changes

Comment: What you are doing in `appendSelectOptions('#select1', data);`? And what `data` you are getting?

Comment: Just creating `<option>` and appending to the select box.  Data is simply an array of Strings

Comment: But aren't you assigning `selected='selected'` to any of these. to set default value? Check the length of `console.log($('#select1 > option').length)` what it returns? May be it is not returning value due to default selected. Or may be your option don't have any value in it. Check that

Comment: Using a debugger statement, at the point of `var selectOneValue= $('#select1').val();` there are no options appended to the select box as the ajax call to get `#select1` data hasn't returned.  But  it still proceeds to make the ajax request to populate `#select2`.  But as `selectOneVal` is null, the call fails

Comment: No, this should not happened we are using promises. Please trace out the `data` in console. or trace the values at every steps. Paste your appendSelectOptions and data here in question window.

Comment: At the point I have indicated, with a debugger statement after `var selectOneValue= $('#select1').val();`, in the network tab, the ajax call to populate `#select1` is shown as 'pending'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164766/discussion-between-anup-yadav-and-user1061799).

Comment: Thanks for your help Anup.  I can't access chat from this machine however.